# How do I output an error without it being returned on the screen?

Tags: powershell

Okay, so I'm writing a very basic PowerShell script (I'm on the newbie side here) that does the following:

- Checks for the version of a running process (output saved to variable)
- If the process is not detected and there is an error, perform an install of program
- If the process version is less than or equal to $version, run a command to upgrade the program

My problem is that if the process is not detected, the command errors out and returns to the prompt. What I really want is for this error (or other responses to the command) to -only- be recorded in the variable, not terminate the script. So if I do:

```
$DesiredVersion = Versionnumber
$ProductVersion = (Get-Process 'process').ProductVersion
if ($ProductVersion -like "*Cannot find*") {
    Start-Process InstallProgram.exe
}
elseif ($ProductVersion -lt $DesiredVersion) {
    Start-Process UpgradeProgram.exe
}
else {
    "Product is up to date"
}
```

and so on, I want the first command to direct any output of the command into the variable without terminating the script (even in event of error). How would I go about doing this?

I tried doing a `Write-Output` command to write everything to a text file. This did not resolve things, the command still returns an error and exits.

Answer (score 1):

Just starting out is the perfect time to get into good habits and use `Try...Catch` constructs:

```
$DesiredVersion = Versionnumber
Try {
    $ProductVersion = (Get-Process 'process' -ErrorAction Stop).ProductVersion
}
Catch {
    "Process not found or error:"
    # $_ contains the error code
    $_
}
# If $ProductVersion has a value then process accordingly
If ($ProductVersion) {
    Try {
        If ($ProductVersion -lt $DesiredVersion) {
            Start-Process UpgradeProgram.exe -ErrorAction Stop
        }
        Else {
            "Product is up to date"
        }
    }
    Catch {
        "Error upgrading:"
        $_
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd make public `$_.Exception` inside a `catch` block… Much more concise, much more readable than full `$_`…

Comment: Okay, this got me much further than before. My one difference in what I need is that if the error occurs because the process is not present, I still need to install the software (rather than upgrade it, or echo that it is not present). I'm examining what I can do during the first Try-Catch to do that by comparing it to the second half of what you wrote.